# C: Doing something when the program exits

Tags: c, exit

In C, if my application ends unexpectedly can I call a function before that happens? I'm writing a flag into a database (processRunning = 1) that prevents other applications from starting a similar process. When the application ends it would not change that flag back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

look into the [`atexit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/) API of the C standard library.

Comment: This is not a solution. It will not protect you from abnormal termination. The `atexit` function is largely useless in practice, and except in small programs that will never get large or turn into libraries, its use should probably be Considered Harmful since it necessarily involves global variables/global state.

Comment: You both probably know this already, but things like network interruptions and power failures can prevent that kind of code from running. It might be more robust to write timestamps to the database every 'n' minutes, and let the database clean up abandoned flags after 'n + m' minutes of no timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful info. So many things you should consider. In my case the above solution is perfectly sufficient because the processes never run longer than 2 minutes. And I check if a process runs more than that it will get killed automatically.

Comment: @Catcall: Polling-based solutions are ugly, wasteful of resources, and suffer from poor robustness. The correct solution is to use a locking mechanism which the OS will automatically unlock when the process dies or the machine reboots.

Comment: @R.: I was under the impression that the OP was writing more to the database than just the flag. If he is, it makes a lot of sense to let the database clean it up. The OS doesn't usually offer any help with that. But if the only use of the database is to store the flag--which seems a strange reason to use a database--then you're right.

Answer (score 5):

On POSIX, the proper solution is to protect the data with a robust mutex in shared memory. If your process has died with a robust mutex held, another program trying to lock the mutex will not deadlock but will instead return `EOWNERDEAD`, and then it has the opportunity to clean up the state protected by the mutex and call `pthread_mutex_consistent`.

**Edit:** If your only want to prevent multiple instances of the program from running, there are surely better/simpler ways, like holding a lock on the database file.

Answer (score 4):

If your application terminates normally, it'll run functions registered through `atexit`. This is a standard function, available on [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tze57ck3.aspx), [unix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atexit.html) and every other platform, and also in [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/).

Note that “terminates normally” means through calls to `exit()` or by returning from `main()`. If your application terminates via `abort()` or `_exit()`, or if it is killed summarily from the outside, it may not have the opportunity to do any cleanup. There may be a better approach, possibly setting and clearing the flag in a wrapper program that does the cleanup regardless of how your program terminates, or dispensing with this flag altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice, Gilles. I was thinking of sth. similar to have an app check every few seconds if the processes attached to a specific PID are still running.

Comment: One solution might be to dabble with catching signals. (I supposed that won't be applicable on Windows.)

Comment: @Frank: Beware that checking by PID isn't foolproof. The PID could be quickly reused by an unrelated process.

Comment: @Victor: Catching signals only works for catchable signals. If the application is SIGKILLed or OOM-killed, or if it crashes, catching signals won't help. (Ok, you can catch SIGSEGV, but it's dodgy. And you just can't catch SIGKILL.)

Comment: Kudos for the wrapper. `atexit` _will_ work for normal termination but not for violent exits.

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways of preventing the application to run twice. One solution is to use **named mutexes** that are system wide. Another and maybe simpler solution is to **lock a file** (open for writing). Even when the application crashes resources are freed by the OS and you will be able to start the application again, because the file or mutex will not be locked anymore.